# Test Moodle plugin without reinstalling the plugin

Tags: moodle

How do I test a Moodle plugin without reinstalling it everytime?

It's pretty annoying if you change a little thing and then you have to change the version in `version.php` and reinstalling the plugin to just find out that what you did is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you are talking about.

If you change the DB definition, then you need an upgrade.php + version.php.

If you change a language string or a stylesheet, then a version.php change is needed for the release, but purging caches will work for a development setup (Site admin > development > purge caches).

If you change a javascript file, then make sure your javascript caching settings are off (in the Moodle site admin settings). Sometimes clearing your browser cache is also needed (and purge caches can also be done if neither of those help).

For new capabilities, events, message types, etc. A version.php bump is needed (although this shouldn't happen very often).

For PHP code changes, you should never need to touch version.php, purge caches or your browser cache.